# Complex integral and parametrization of a circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to compute the following integral of $$\int \frac{1}{z^3+3} dz$$ over a circle of radius $2$, centerd at $(2,0)$. Thus I am trying to compute the residue and have found that the function has poles at $$3^{\frac{1}{3}}\left[ \frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2} \right], \; i3^{\frac{1}{3}}, \text{ and } -3^{\frac{1}{3}} \left[ \frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{2} \right].$$ However, we have to make sure that all the roots lie inside our parameter. My conjecture is they all lie inside our given parameter. Thus, is there any "formal" way to prove that those poles lie inside the given circle?

Comment: Your middle root is wrong. Draw a picture, for goodness' sake!

Comment: Your middle root should be $-3^{1/3}$.  Beyond that, @TedShifrin is right.  Draw a picture, or alternatively compute $|2 - r_i|^2$ for each of the roots $r_i$ of $z^3+3$.  If $|2-r_i|^2 < 4$, then $r_i$ lies inside the circle, if $|2-r_i|^2>4$, then $r_i$ lies outside the circle, and if $|2-r_i|^2=4$, then $r_i$ lies on the circle.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks for the answer. I feel stupid to have missed such a simple point! Thanks again